# React, passport async request to login instead of pageload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, passport.js

I am trying to find a way to request login without having to reload the page. Right now I have an `<form action="/login">`, however I want to achieve this like with jquery Ajax, but I am not familiar with the vanilla ES6 / reactway of doing this.. Any chance you could update me?

Server.js

```
var router = express.Router(); 

var passport = require('passport');
var Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var db = require('./db');


// Configure the local strategy for use by Passport.
//
// The local strategy require a `verify` function which receives the credentials
// (`username` and `password`) submitted by the user.  The function must verify
// that the password is correct and then invoke `cb` with a user object, which
// will be set at `req.user` in route handlers after authentication.
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));


// Configure Passport authenticated session persistence.
//
// In order to restore authentication state across HTTP requests, Passport needs
// to serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  The
// typical implementation of this is as simple as supplying the user ID when
// serializing, and querying the user record by ID from the database when
// deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
  cb(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, cb) {
  db.users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { return cb(err); }
    cb(null, user);
  });
});
```

Login page:

```
import React from 'react'
import FullWidthSection from '../../FullWidthSection'
import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

import style from './login-style.css'
const Login = withRouter(
  React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            usernameFocus: false,
            passwordFocus: false,
            usernameValidate: false,
            passwordValidate: false
        };
    },
    handleSubmit: function(e) {
      // We check for all input fields to be valid ( TODO: Should give user some feedback if not valid )
      if(this.state.usernameValidate && this.state.passwordValidate){

      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      console.log("skicka")

    },
    usernameFocus: function() {
      this.setState({
        usernameFocus: true
      })
    },

    passwordFocus: function() {
      this.setState({
        passwordFocus: true
      })
    },

    validateUsername: function (e) {
      var inputVal = e.target.value;
      var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      var validate = re.test(inputVal);

      if(validate) {
        this.setState({
          usernameValidate: true
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          usernameValidate: false
        })
      }
    },
    validatePassword: function (e) {
      var inputVal = e.target.value;
      // Just check if password contains more than 3 characters.
      if(inputVal.length > 3){
        this.setState({
          passwordValidate: true
        })
      } else {
        this.setState({
          passwordValidate: false
        })
      }
    },
    render() {
      var usernameFocus = this.state.usernameFocus;
      var passwordFocus = this.state.passwordFocus;
      var usernameValidated = this.state.usernameValidate;
      var passwordValidated = this.state.passwordValidate;

      return (
        <FullWidthSection>
         <div className="login-background">
            <div className="login-wrapper">
              <div className="container">
                <Row>
                  <Col lg={6} lgOffset={3} md={8} mdOffset={2}>
                    <div className="login-form clearfix">
                      <div className="left">
                        <div className="logo">

                         <img src="/images/animus_logo_blacktext.png" />  
                        </div>
                      </div> 


                      <div className="right">
                        <h2>Welcome back</h2> 
                        <form action="/login" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                          <label htmlFor="username" onClick={this.usernameFocus}>E-mail</label>
                          <input ref="email" type="text" name="username" onFocus={this.usernameFocus} onChange={this.validateUsername} className={(usernameFocus ? "toggled" : "") + " " + (usernameValidated ? "validated" : "")} />

                          <label htmlFor="password" onClick={this.passwordFocus}>Password</label>
                          <input ref="pass" name="password" type="password" onFocus={this.passwordFocus} onChange={this.validatePassword} className={(passwordFocus ? "toggled" : "") + " " + (passwordValidated ? "validated" : "")} />
                          <a href="#" className="forgotpw">Forgot your password?</a>

                          <input type="submit" value="Login" autoComplete="new-password" />
                          Need an account? <a href="#" className="register">Register</a>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </FullWidthSection>
      )
    }
  })
)

const Logout = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    auth.logout()
  },  

  render() {
    return <p>You are now logged out</p>
  }
})

module.exports = {
    Login: Login,
    Logout: Logout
}
```

Comment: Can you add code you have?

Comment: Done, I updated firstpost @Bwaxxlo